# Как сравнить восьмеричную цифру

Tags: c++, winapi

У меня есть: `GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), NULL))` вывод у неё типа: `04090409`или `04190419` какой тип мне выбрать для этих цифр? сравнить с помощью if не получается.

немного начального кода

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow)
{
    HKL layout = GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), NULL));
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("file.txt", ios::app);
    fout << layout << endl;
    fout.close();
}



//ID раскладок
//ENG = 04090409
//RU == 04190419
```

Comment: Мне кажется тут был чуть другой вопрос. Верните как было, если хотите задать другой вопрос - создайте новый.

Comment: ЦП всёравно восьмеричная цифра или десятичная. Главное что бы одной системы было - сравнение идёт без проблем. Два layout - можно проверить на равенство без проблем. (Это ответ на "второй вопрос")

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то `HKL` - это `void*`, и при выводе выводится в 16-ричном формате. А содержит он

> The return value is the input locale identifier for the thread. The low word contains a Language Identifier for the input language and the high word contains a device handle to the physical layout of the keyboard.

Вы можете использовать стандартные макросы `LOWORD` и `HIWORD` для получения младшего слова и старшего соответственно. И сравнивать то, что там уж вам надо, и как надо...

Comment: Кто-то недобросовесно поламал вопрос, не было же "восьмеричной" цифры? Или я недоглядел?

Comment: @nick_n_a было)